# Missing PG headers ( trying to install Postgres gem for Rails with Brew )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, pg

```
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Seems to be the issue, it's from this tail:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

My steps to reproduce this on a Mountain Lion Mac OS is :

1. `brew install postgresql`
2. `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

I've tried to pinpoint different pg_config's through my computer. The one in Brew's cellar, the one cp'd  by Brew to `/user/local`, and another one that might have been from a previous download of it. None of them work.

**UPDATE**

Just tried to install without the config-options. And got an lol:

```
ruby extconf.rb --without-pg-config
checking for pg_config... yes
```

Comment: did you `brew unlink` and uninstalled all versions first?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm starting to think this might be an rvm issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started imagining that my issue had something to do with RVM as the bottom of the trace it said.. :

```
"You need to download development tools"
```

Then I did :

```
$ rvm autolibs enable
$ rvm requirements
```

Then I went ahead and just updated my ruby ( if you don't do this, then I recommend just reinstalling it your current one. *I could not do this without `autolibs enable`* ) :

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

Boom! Solved!!!! `(:D :D :D :D :D) x 1,000,000`